# AJAX not updating the list from MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

i am inserting from a form data into my database, after i create a file with a FOR loop that i display all the records from my table. I am trying to refresh my list with data on a page without refresh every time when there was inserted new data into database.

main.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function fetch(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/ajax.php',
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery(data).hide().prependTo("#list").slideDown("slow");
                if(jQuery("#list li").length > 15){
                    jQuery('#list li:gt(14)').remove();
                }
                setTimeout("fetch()", 1000);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

PHP / HTML

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/wp-blog-header.php");
session_start();

wp_enqueue_style('il_style_mode');
wp_enqueue_style('il_admin_style_mode');
wp_enqueue_scripts('jquery');

global $_IL_ID;
global $_IL_LIMIT;
global $_IL_TOTAL;
global $wpdb;

$_IL_TABLE_NAME_INTERNAL       = $wpdb->prefix . "il_internal_transfer";
$_SESSION['IL_COUNT_ADMIN'] = 1;

require_once ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/wp-content/plugins/il_mt4_client_area/il_request/il_internal_transfer/il_internal_admin/il_internal_transfer_tabs.php");

$_IL_START = 0;
$_IL_LIMIT = 10;

if( isset($_GET['paged']) ){
    $_IL_ID = $_GET['paged'];
    $_IL_START = ($_IL_ID-1) * $_IL_LIMIT;
}

$_IL_QUERY_INTERNAL = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $_IL_TABLE_NAME_INTERNAL ORDER BY il_id DESC LIMIT $_IL_START, $_IL_LIMIT");
$_IL_NUM_ROWS_INTERNAL_ALL = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $_IL_TABLE_NAME_INTERNAL");

echo '<span class="il_admin_main_title">';
echo '<span>';
echo '<h2>Internal Transfers</h2>';
echo '</span>';
echo '<span>';
require_once ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/wp-content/plugins/il_mt4_client_area/il_request/il_internal_transfer/il_internal_admin/il_internal_transfer_sub_tabs.php");
echo '</span>';
echo '</span>';

echo '<span class="il_admin_transactions_block" id="il_admin_transactions_block">';

if( $_IL_NUM_ROWS_INTERNAL_ALL < 1 ){
    include ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/wp-content/plugins/il_mt4_client_area/il_include/il_messages/il_internal_transfer_sorry.php");
}else{

    require_once ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/ajax.php");

}

echo '</span>';


if(isset($_POST['il_status_update'])){
    $wpdb->update(
        $_IL_TABLE_NAME_INTERNAL,
        array(
            'il_status' => $_POST['il_status_new'],
        ),
        array( 'il_id' => $_POST['il_transaction_id'] ),
        array(
            '%s',
        ),
        array( '%s' )
    );
};

if(isset($_POST['il_delete'])){
    $wpdb->delete( $_IL_TABLE_NAME_INTERNAL, array( 'il_id' => $_POST['il_transaction_id'] ), array( '%d' ) );
};

$_IL_ROWS_COUNT = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from $_IL_TABLE_NAME_INTERNAL"));
$_IL_TOTAL = ceil( $_IL_ROWS_COUNT / $_IL_LIMIT );

if($_IL_LIMIT < $_IL_ROWS_COUNT){
echo '<span class="il_pagination_block_admin">';
if( $_IL_ID > 1 )
{
    echo "<a href='?page=il_internal_transfer&tab=il_internal_transfer&paged=".($_IL_ID-1)."' class='il_pagination_prev'><span class='il_pagination_prev_icon'></span></a>";
}

echo "<ul class='il_pagination'>";
for( $i = 1; $i <= $_IL_TOTAL; $i++ )
{
    if( $i == $_IL_ID ) { echo "<li class='il_pagination_current'>".$i."</li>"; }

    else { echo "<li><a href='?page=il_internal_transfer&tab=il_internal_transfer&paged=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>"; }
}
echo "</ul>";
if( $_IL_ID != $_IL_TOTAL )
{
    echo "<a href='?page=il_internal_transfer&tab=il_internal_transfer&paged=".( $_IL_ID + 1 )."' class='il_pagination_next'><span class='il_pagination_next_icon'></span></a>";
}

echo "</span>";
}else{

}
?>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/wp-blog-header.php");
wp_enqueue_style('il_style_mode');
wp_enqueue_style('il_admin_style_mode');
wp_enqueue_scripts('jquery');
global $wpdb;



$_IL_TABLE_NAME_INTERNAL       = $wpdb->prefix . "il_internal_transfer";
$_IL_QUERY_INTERNAL = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $_IL_TABLE_NAME_INTERNAL ORDER BY il_id DESC LIMIT $_IL_START, $_IL_LIMIT");
echo '<ul id="list">';
foreach($_IL_QUERY_INTERNAL as $_IL_RESULT_DATA)
{
    ?>
    <li>
        <span class="il_admin_transactions_block_raw_block">

        <form method="post">
            <input type='hidden' name='il_transaction_id' value="<?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_id ?>"  />
            <span class="il_admin_transactions_block_raw">

                <span class="il_admin_transactions_block_raw_count"><?php echo $_SESSION['IL_COUNT_ADMIN'] ?></span>
                <span class="il_admin_internal_block_raw_full_name">
                    <?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_name ?>
                </span>
                <span class="il_admin_internal_block_raw_from_to">
                    <span><?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_from_mt4 ?></span> <?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_from_mt4_currency ?>
                    <img src="/wp-content/plugins/il_mt4_client_area/il_images/il_icons/il_gray_left_icon.png" class="il_arrow_between" />
                    <span><?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_to_mt4 ?></span> <?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_to_mt4_currency ?>
                </span>
                <span class="il_admin_internal_block_raw_email"><?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_email ?></span>
                <span class="il_admin_internal_block_raw_date"><?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_date ?></span>

            </span>

            <span class="il_admin_transactions_block_raw_extras">
                <?php if( $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_comments === NULL || empty($_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_comments) ){ ?>

                <?php } else { ?>
                    <span class="il_admin_transactions_block_raw_comment">
                        <span>Comment:</span>
                        <span><?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_comments ?></span>
                    </span>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php if( $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_status == 'approved' ){ ?>

                <?php } else { ?>
                    <span class="il_admin_transactions_block_raw_extras_status_icon">
                        <img src="/wp-content/plugins/il_mt4_client_area/il_images/il_icons/il_green_status_<?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_status ?>_icon.gif" alt="Processing" title="Processing"/>
                    </span>
                <?php } ?>

                <span class="il_admin_transactions_block_raw_extras_ip">
                    The transaction was done from this ip <?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_user_ip ?>
                </span>

                <span class="il_admin_transactions_block_raw_extras_ip_select">
                <?php if( $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_status == 'approved' ){ ?>
                    <span class="il_admin_transactions_block_raw_extras_status_<?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_status ?>"><?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_status ?></span>
                    <img src="/wp-content/plugins/il_mt4_client_area/il_images/il_icons/il_green_status_<?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_status ?>_icon.gif" alt="Processing" title="Processing" width="20"/>
                <?php } else { ?>

                    <span class="il_admin_transactions_block_raw_extras_update">
                        <select name="il_status_new">
                            <option>approved</option>
                            <option>waiting</option>
                            <option>rejected</option>
                        </select>
                    </span>

                    <span class="il_admin_transactions_block_raw_extras_update_button">
                        <input type="submit" name="il_status_update" value="update status" />
                        <input type="submit" name="il_delete" value="delete" class="il_admin_transactions_delete_button" />
                    </span>

                <?php } ?>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span class="il_clear"></span>
        </form>

       </span>
    </li>
    <?php
    $_SESSION['IL_COUNT_ADMIN']++;

}

echo '</ul>';
```

actually what i am trying is every time when new data will be inserted in my table i want to display them automatically in my list using the loop from ajax.php

Comment: Can you tell us what the issue is?

Comment: the issue is that the list is not updating, like the ajax request is not working, i fixed something in my request and it start to request my ajax.php every second but still the list was not refreshing with new data, my problem is that until now what i did with ajax is not working @JayBlanchard

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's console to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Are you calling `fetch()` anywhere? If no: why not? If yes: what is the console output?

Comment: yes of course i was calling the function, when i call it i get only the id i target, the output is like this <ul id="list"></ul> @JayBlanchard

Comment: like emphy output, but no idea why @JayBlanchard

Comment: and as well i do not have any errors, seems everything is fine, but is not doing what i need @JayBlanchard

Comment: Make sure your query works on a stand-alone basis. Then make sure they work in the context of the PHP you're running.

Comment: all the code is working, first i wrote everything simple without ajax request, so if working fine, just i can not implement until the end this ajax request, maybe u have a different approach? @JayBlanchard